# Push to Hystrix Turbine instead of the Turbine polling?

Tags: java, polling, netflix

I am setting up Netflix's Hystrix. But because of firewalls the Hystrix Turbine cannot poll the server pool. However nodes in the server pool can push event data to the Turbine. The naive way is to set up a intermediary server that individual nodes push and the Turbine polls this server. Is there a better way for individual nodes to push the event data to the Turbine?